# Choosing a specific model of a Lawvere Theory

Tags: category-theory

Models for [Lawvere theories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) are functors that preserve products. I'm a little confused about this detail: suppose you have a Lawvere theory for groups. If you have a specific group in mind, is there an obvious way to pick the functor so that it represents that group?

Comment: AFAIK it just sends $1$ to the underlying set of a group, and $\pi: 1 \times 1 \to 1$ - to the group operation.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I think that's the answer.